# TextView collapsing on setText

Tags: android, textview

I've created a text line using some TextViews one behind another, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#9b9b9b" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
            android:textColor="@color/$selectAll" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
            android:textColor="@color/$addRed" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageMiddle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
            android:textColor="@color/$selectAll" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageEnd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/$selectAll" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I programatically set the different texts, all was working nicely. But, when I added styling attributes, sometimes, the length of the TextView is set to nothing even if it contains some text.

I don't call any `setLayoutParams()` in my code, so I guess the wrap_content mechanics are the key of this, but I can't figure out what's happening…

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Your layout looks fine. It sounds like you're calling `setText()` with an empty/null string. Also make sure you aren't passing an `int` to `setText()`.

Comment: Yes, I sometimes have that kind of statement: `textView.setText("");`, but when I set a text back, the TextView's lenght doesn't follow.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, your `LinearLayout` shouldn't have `textColor` and `textSize`, but that shouldn't make a difference. I've never seen `$` in a color reference before - not sure about that.
But the `TextView` width should adjust to the new content. I can only suggest making 100% sure the new content is not empty and not an `int`.

Comment: I thought the attributes would have a knock-on effect on the children views, but I might have been wrong on this point. The dollar sign in the color name is part of the project I'm working on and I'm sure every text is correct. I've tested this through a `Log` message.

Comment: When replacing `setText("")` with `setText("*")`, everything runs smoothly. Is there a way to have an "invisible text" ? Maybe should I use some `setVisibility()` trick?